# How to compare a slice to a string?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {

    msg := make([]byte, 1024)

    //Basic variables
    port := ":2002"
    protocol := "udp"

    //Build the address
    myaddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr(protocol, port)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Wrong Address")
        return
    }

    //Output
    fmt.Println("Reading " + protocol + " from " + myaddr.String())

    //Create the connection
    connection, err := net.ListenUDP(protocol, myaddr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    //receive msg
    for {
        _, useraddr, err := connection.ReadFromUDP(msg)
        fmt.Println("msg from :", useraddr)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Some error  %v", err)
            continue
        }
        go sendResponse(connection, useraddr)
    }
}
```

This is my UDP server, I'm making a game. So I want, if the client send "let's play", the server to run the `go sendresponse` function. If it's not "let's play " it will not run.

I think I should compare `msg` but I don't know how. Thank you :)

Comment: You'd have to loop through the slice and compare it byte by byte, as the string "let's play", though a slice of bytes, does not have the length of 1024 that `msg` has.

Comment: I really didn't understand nothing, can you please write the code

Comment: You could start with going through the Tour of Go one more time to refresh and solidify you Go skills. SO is not a "write code for me service".

Comment: Are you asking, as the title suggests, how to compare a string to an array of chars?  Or are you asking, as the post suggests, the best way to determine when to send a response?  Either way, please **format** your code and provide a _minimal_ snippet.

Comment: This is not the place for "please write the code".  To determine what types of questions are appropriate for SO, please review this topic on the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: but this is a place for "please help me"

Comment: No it is not: Reddit or golang-nuts is the place for "please help me" and as you crossposted there https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/8qixs1/how_to_compare_a_slice_to_a_string/ you might get an answer there.

Comment: and I did get an answer there thank you for nothing

Comment: This is indeed a place for "please help me", but we do have specific requirements for our content to make it as useful as possible.  Questions need background, an MVCE (if applicable), and a pointed question.  A general "please write the code" is not appropriate, but if you have done your research, we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, something like this:

```
//receive msg
msg := make([]byte, 1024)
for {
    n, useraddr, err := connection.ReadFromUDP(msg[:cap(msg)])
    msg = msg[:n]
    fmt.Println("msg from :", useraddr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Some error  %v", err)
        continue
    }
    if string(msg) == "let's play" {
        go sendResponse(connection, useraddr)
    }
}
```

The expression `msg[:cap(msg)]` sets the `msg` buffer length to its full capacity.

The statement `msg = msg[:n]` sets the `msg` buffer length to the actual length read.

The `string(msg)` expression converts the `msg` type `[]byte` to type `string` for the comparison.